# ASP.NET - Validate Excel File Content

Tags: javascript, asp.net, excel

I have a page with a file input where the user is supposed to upload an excel file to insert a large amount of records to a specific table. I found this Javascript code to help validate if the inserted file has one of the requested Excel extensions:

```
var hash = {
    'xls': 1,
    'xlsx': 1,
};

function checkExtension() {
    var filename = $("#uploadFile").val();
    var re = /\..+$/;
    var ext = filename.slice(filename.lastIndexOf(".") + 1).toLowerCase();
    if (hash[ext]) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Invalid file type. Please insert a valid Excel file.");
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, as efficient as this code is at validating the file's extension, it won't validate the file's content allowing someone to upload a file with different type of content but it's extension renamed to ".xls" or ".xlsx". How can i get around this scenario?

Comment: From my perspective, in the client side, you cloud validate file type or other shallow stuff like file size, for example. But actually, check if this file is excel file in the server side.

Comment: Try and open the file server side with a library like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus). If it fails the file is not Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can Properly Validate Your Excel File in 3 steps

1. In Asp.net FileUploader Control has an Attribute Called 'accept' `<asp:FileUploader accept='.xls,.xlsx'/>`. It will by default let the user to select only xls and xlsx extension file. However still user can choose All file options to upload another file.
2. Verify if the Extension of the Filename contains .xls from Javascript as well as Code Behind.
3. Use Aspose.Cells dll and try to fetch the xls file it will return Exception 'InvalidFileFormatException' if the File is not xls or xlsx.